# Interstitial Ads For Iphone Preload

Tags: swift, iad

I am trying to implement an interstitial ad for iPhone.  My code currently works, but the ads are slow to appear (I know that I need to check if an ad is available).  Is there a way to initiate iAd at start up, maybe in the appDelegate so that when my view appears the ad is ready?

Here is how my views are laid out.

Gameplay_View -> Score -> Ad -> Gameplay_View

Since I'm using three separate UIViews I'm not sure how to implement the Ad and have it load in a timely manner.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I know there is a line of code available for ads to be preloaded, i haven't managed to try it out yet but if your curious here it is.

This is how i declared my Interstitial Ad (Just as a reference since the line of code uses the name).

```
var interstitialAd:ADInterstitialAd!
```

When the game has ended have this line of code and it is 'meant' to preload the interstitial ads for the current view controller (I say again i have not tested this to see if it works, this is just if your curious).

```
UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()
```